# Neo4j not started or is taking a lot of time

Tags: ubuntu, neo4j

After importing offline database in neo4j data/databases/ directory, it is taking a lot of time start. All it shows even after 20 mins :

I'm using systemctl start neo4j to start the instance.

```
neo4j.service - Neo4j Graph Database
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/neo4j.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: active (running) since Mi 2017-05-31 23:55:42 CEST; 465ms ago
Main PID: 11348 (java)


 CGroup: /system.slice/neo4j.service
       └─11348 /usr/bin/java -cp /var/lib/neo4j/plugins:/etc/neo4j:/usr/share/neo4j/lib/*:/var/lib/neo4j/plugi

Mai 31 23:55:42 gaurav-LINUX neo4j[11348]: Directories in use:
Mai 31 23:55:42 gaurav-LINUX neo4j[11348]:   home:         /var/lib/neo4j
Mai 31 23:55:42 gaurav-LINUX neo4j[11348]:   config:       /etc/neo4j
Mai 31 23:55:42 gaurav-LINUX neo4j[11348]:   logs:         /var/log/neo4j
Mai 31 23:55:42 gaurav-LINUX neo4j[11348]:   plugins:      /var/lib/neo4j/plugins
Mai 31 23:55:42 gaurav-LINUX neo4j[11348]:   import:       NOT SET
Mai 31 23:55:42 gaurav-LINUX neo4j[11348]:   data:         /var/lib/neo4j/data
Mai 31 23:55:42 gaurav-LINUX neo4j[11348]:   certificates: /var/lib/neo4j/certificates
Mai 31 23:55:42 gaurav-LINUX neo4j[11348]:   run:          /var/run/neo4j
Mai 31 23:55:42 gaurav-LINUX neo4j[11348]: Starting Neo4j.
lines 1-17/17 (END)
```

I'm using Ubuntu16